# Story about people who absorb the evil acts of others "sin eaters". Think this is a fairly old one

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My memory of this is fairly thin. But I know it's real and I read it in probably an anthology. I think it might have been fairly short. The concept of the sin eater pops up in other literature from time to time as well. Unfortunately I am unable to cite examples. I think I remember references to sin eaters being members of a caste. The idea as best I can explain is that the sin eater agrees to take on the responsibilities, guilt and karmic costs of a sin committed by another person either as a duty related to the sin eaters cast, or in exchange for money or valuables. The person or entity that originally committed the sin is then free of the consequences. I think this story was written before 1965.

Comment: Is it not The Sin Eater By Margaret Atwood ?

Comment: Juvian, I think not. though this is interesting enough that I will make a point of reading it. I think she might be too contemporary and her book is fiction not science fiction. But I will check into it more, date published etc. I find the Welsh connection interesting.

Comment: Anything else you remember? Except for the judaism part, it fits the description of every sin eater story

Comment: This sounds like the movie The Order. Has the sin eaters, though it is a Christian secret sect.

Comment: Jovian , every other? Are they all sci fi? How many are there? And no, I'm sorry I can't remember much else except the era- sometime before 1965

Comment: And for now let's forget judiasm

Comment: Yes, we need more. There are *lots* of sin-eater stories (*Morpheus Road* and *The Sin-Eater's Daughter* just in recent memory). I am voting to close as too broad until sufficient detail is added. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah sorry I'll try to dredge up more. I did'nt think there was so much out there.

Comment: i thought I mentioned in the body of the question, before 1965.

Comment: I guess I put the date in a comment

Comment: So I'm doin some digging on my own (should a done it before) it could be Elisabeth Walter. She wrote The Sin Eater before 1965. I'm going to see if I can find something else.

Comment: The thread I remember in the story I'm thinking of was I think darker than the one Elisabeth presents. But I was much younger then so I'm sure my perception is different now.

Comment: Thanks 14111 I saw that on line too,  but was unable to tease out the date and particulars like you were. I'll check it out

Comment: I think I underestimated the history of the concept of the sin eater and the multiplicity of it's treatment in literature. I thought mistakenly it came out of Sci Fi. Now I suspect in fact that it is very old and a result of Christianity's focus on sin. I would bet that actual sin eaters have existed for hundreds of years. How it got into Sci Fi, I guess goes to my belief as an artist that 95% of art is derivative. The rest is inspiration and personal interpretation.

Comment: So given that Fiona Macleod wrote her The Sin Eaters in 1895, I think the short story Elisabeth Walter wrote thirty years later is the one I read sometime around 1960. She like all authors, being well read would almost certainly have come across MacLoed's work which appears to have been presented as spiritual writing. So this is her Sci Fi take on the subject.